# Discovering highest point in area using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, elevation

I'll preface by saying I've never used or even heard of GIS software previously, so I'm sorry for being very clueless.

My goal is to find the highest point in Highgate (in London, England).

I have downloaded the "OS Terrain 50" from the [Ordinance Survey download page](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html), and have opened it up in QGIS. Unfortunately, I think I misunderstood as this only shows me the contours.

Where should I be looking for height data, and how would I interpret it? I expect I'm struggling because I'm Googling all the wrong things.

Comment: So I would recommend starting with some research and reading.  Contour data is a vector product.  You probably want something more in line of a raster such as USGS DEM, SRTM, or DTED.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USGS_DEM  Given the differences in the type of data, you can then use different tools.  I prefer to load the data with GDAL in Python and search the raster manually.  This is a decent tutorial using QGIS for analyzing DEM data as well. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_terrain.html

Comment: The OS download page also provides a 50m grid download, maybe that would be more appropriate?

Comment: If you want to find the highest contour... open the attribute table and then click on the height data column. Like a filter in Excel, this will order the data low through high. Write down the highest value, then use the filter option to select only values equal to that. This will give you the contours containg the highest point. Stick a base map under it...

Comment: You should look at this blog post on calculating borough high spots in London using the same dataset: http://oobrien.com/2014/08/borough-tops/